# Determine Android app's last update time during development?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am trying to get a timestamp of when the currently running Android app was updated during development (e.g. a new APK installed by Android Studio or ADB.). I have tried the following, but both timestamps do not update even though the app has been updated:

```
val pm: PackageManager = this.getPackageManager()
val appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(this.packageName, 0)
val appFile: String = appInfo.sourceDir

val lastWriteTime = File(appFile).lastModified()
val lastUpdateTime = this.getPackageManager()
                         .getPackageInfo(this.packageName, 0).lastUpdateTime
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, the lastUpdateTime is 1653240000762 which in my time zone is 2022-05-22 13:20:00 -0400.  That is about 12 days in the past as of this writing. The lastWriteTime is 1653239999000 which is 2022-05-22 13:19:59 -0400.

I just re-ran this code from AndroidStudio about one hour ago on 2022-06-03 14:00:00 -0400.  Why did the timestamp not change?  I know for sure the app was updated because before this change, the code lines shown were not there to show up in the debugger!

[image]

There must be a way to do this.  Clearly, the code has changed on the Android device.  How can I get a measurement of when that happened?

The reason I want this is because I am a developer of an Android library, and I want to make the library clear out some cache information when it detects a new app install during development to make things easier on the app developer.

Comment: Are you sure the `PackageInfo.lastUpdateTime` is not changing? From what I've observed so far that value is consistent, at least on emulators. If that is indeed buggy, maybe you can try capturing a broadcast intent of `Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` which you can directly register the broadcast receiver to the Android manifest. That broadcast should be fired for the app when it gets updated.

Comment: If you want to track down other apps' updates, you might need a foreground service with other package actions such as `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` which cannot be registered to manifest directly.

Comment: @FurkanYurdaknl I added a screenshot showing the values in the debugger after I just ran the code, along with an update to the question explaining what those timestamps mean vs. what time it really is when I ran the test.   My understanding of ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is that it does not fire for debug build installations, so I don't think this will help.   I only need a solution for my own app not other installed apps.

Comment: Why are you using the timestamp?  Embed a version number in your library.  Write that version number to shared preference at startup.  Then when you're launched, see if the version has changed.  If so, clear the cache.  That makes much more sense than looking at install time-  you'll have far fewer false positives.  Even better your version number can be updated only when the cache format changes and you need to update it.

Comment: That's a fine solution for other use cases, but in my case I am trying to detect any time during **development** that the developer re-ran the app from Android Studio and clear the cache. I can't rely on a version number change because it is not realistic to expect developers to change the version between every single debugging run of the app after a minor change.

Comment: I think you are forgetting that `adb install --fastdeploy` exists for incremental updates. Not sure if that is the cause of the lack of change, but unless you get the developer to disable Android Studio features you may be better off setting a 'debug/developer flag' for your library to update cache every time (bonus add library logging etc.) and of course explain in your library documentation.

Comment: I agree that fastdeploy probably is a factor here.  But I am surprised that I have been able to find no deploy timestamp change whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If I clearly understood your problem, following approach may help you (actually, it may be not the best solution):

1. Via gradle add constant for timestamp or date:

```
static def timestamp() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis()
}
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "Long", "BUILD_TIMESTAMP", timestamp()
    }
}
```

2. On your main activity at onCreate send `BuildConfig.BUILD_TIMESTAMP` and current system timestamp wherever you want. For example, write simple web service that accepts such requests and saves it at remote database.

If you want to track only unique installations, you can use instead of build timestamp hash sum for installation apk somehow or use self written code generation lib that would calc hash sum for sources (for example).

Edit: Or you can calc sources hash at build.gradle directly.

Comment: That is a good solution, @akaish.  Unfortunately it won't work for me, because as the Android library developer, I don't control the app build setup for the Android apps that use my library.  I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without having to make changes to the app project -- I can only make changes to the underlying library project.